# Solving "The query returns a type that is currently not supported" in Connected Sheets?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm running into a challenge when using Connected Sheets to interact with BigQuery. The following query fails to execute.

```
IF TRUE THEN
  SELECT "Some message" AS `msg`;
END IF;
```

The Connected Sheets query editor invalidates this statement with the following error.

```
The query returns a type that is currently not supported.
```

Without the IF statement the query obviously runs just fine.

The same error is displayed when trying to run a BigQuery stored procedure for instance using something like this.

```
CALL my_dataset.my_sp()
```

What could be going on here?

Answer (score 0):

From what I'm reading in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting), you need to return what you are trying to select outside of the if statement. So you would need something like this

```
DECLARE x STRING DEFAULT "Test message";
IF TRUE THEN
  SELECT "Some message" AS `msg`;
  SET x = msg;
END IF;
SELECT x;
```

You will probably need to edit this to work though, I have never used bigquery before

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't doesn't work either. In BigQuery the IF statement works just fine. The problem only occurs when you try to use it in Connected Sheets. But so far I haven't found any documentation which describes which queries are supported and which ones aren't.